# Question About Summation of Summations

Tags: summation

I am trying to figure out the value of $$\sum_{i=2}^4\sum_{j=2}^i j$$

I thought of having a two for loops, one nested inside of the other, so:

```
for(int i = 2; i <= 4; ++i) {
    for(int j = 2; j <= i; ++j) {
        sum += j;
    }
}
```

So I got:

**i = 2, j = 2:** 2

**i = 3, j = 2:** 2 + 2

**i = 3, j = 3:** 2 + 2 + 3

**i = 4, j = 2:** 2 + 2 + 3 + 2

**i = 4, j = 3:** 2 + 2 + 3 + 2 + 3

**i = 4, j = 4:** 2 + 2 + 3 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 16

But I know this is the incorrect answer, and I'm not sure why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what do you think is the correct answer

Comment: Why are you so sure this is incorrect? I don't see anything particularly wrong.

Comment: Note that $\sum_{j=2}^i j=\frac{i(i+1)}{2}-1$. So, you may use this.

Comment: the top answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238834/how-do-you-write-the-summation-of-a-summation is why I think my answer is incorrect

Comment: Better to use `i++` and similar.

Comment: How is that sum relevant? It's the sum of $1/j$ not $j$, and $n$ is arbitrary, not necessarily $4$.

Comment: I know, but I wanted to give an example without any arbitrary variables, and the idea is the same regardless whether its 1/j or j

Comment: Oh each line is being summed up!

Comment: Looks right to me

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations are fine. Recall the sigma operator $\sum$ works as follows:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=a}^bf(i)=f(a)+f(a+1)+\cdots+f(b)
\end{align*}

> We obtain by first expanding the outer sum and then the inner sum:
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i=2}^4}\color{blue}{\sum_{j=2}^i  j}
> &=\sum_{j=2}^2j+\sum_{j=2}^3j+\sum_{j=2}^4j\\
> &=(2)+(2+3)+(2+3+4)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=16}
> \end{align*}